# Counter plays when reach the section on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, count

i have the next script to count some stats and i want to know how to make it to be played when the scroll reach his section.

How we saw from the script, the script autoplay when page onload i think.

Maybe i will need to change the script but i haven't found another script for this, if you know some scripts, please tell me.

```js
 (function($) {
  "use strict";
  function count($this){
  var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
  current = current + 1; /* Where 50 is increment */ 
  $this.html(++current);
   if(current > $this.data('count')){
    $this.html($this.data('count'));
   } else {    
    setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
   }
  }         
  $(".stat-count").each(function() {
    $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
    $(this).html('0');
    count($(this));
  });
   })(jQuery);
```

```css
.stat {
   margin:150px auto;
   text-align:center;
}
.highlight {
   color:#111;
   padding:20px 0;
   font-weight:bold;
   display:block;
   overflow:hidden;
   margin-bottom:0;
   font-size:48px;
}
.stat i {
 color:#f7c221;
}
.milestone-details {
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:18px;
   color:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="stat">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="milestone-counter">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
                    <span class="stat-count highlight">122</span>
                    <div class="milestone-details">Happy Customers</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="milestone-counter">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-3x"></i>
                    <span class="stat-count highlight">4226</span>
                    <div class="milestone-details">Ordered Coffee's</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="milestone-counter">
                    <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x"></i>
                    <span class="stat-count highlight">14</span>
                    <div class="milestone-details">Awards Win</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="milestone-counter">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera fa-3x"></i>
                    <span class="stat-count highlight">232</span>
                    <div class="milestone-details">Photos Taken</div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div><!-- stat -->
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery InView](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) plugin.

```
$('.milestone-counter').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    count($(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't working or maybe im doing something wrong.. I added the script from you in <head></head>

Comment: @BogdanCreativeVisuals Did you also add the plugin to your project? The code I provided assumes you know how to add third-party jQuery plugins.